# How to add stanford corenlp library in Eclipse/Netbeans IDE for Java NLP Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to do a NLP project using Java for that I want to set up Stanford Core NLP in eclipse or netbeans IDE for developement.How should I do my initial Setup ?

I have tried some installation methods but its not working.I have also used Maven, but its not working.

1. Missing artifact edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:jar:${stanford.corenlp.version}   pom.xml /stanford-coreNLP   line 22 Maven Dependency Problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your version placeholder cannot be resolved. Either state the version explicitly

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/edu.stanford.nlp/stanford-corenlp -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Or define the version in your pom.xml as a property:

```
<project>
<properties>
    <stanford.corenlp.version>3.9.2</stanford.corenlp.version>
</properties>
...
</project>
```